# Using a temp folder to run a test with testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I am using testthat to run tests on my own package and I have now a test that throws the error, which previously worked fine. The general structure of my test is:

```
test_that("my.test", {
  new <- system.file("extdata", "my.new.file.xml", package="my.pkg")
  old <- system.file("extdata", "my.old.file.xml", package="my.pkg")
  csv.in <- system.file("extdata", "my.data.csv", package="my.pkg")
  testFolder <- tempdir()
  file.copy(c(new, old, csv.in), testFolder)

  #Do something with the files and run tests

  files <- list.files(testFolder, full.names=TRUE)
  file.remove(files)
})
```

However, the line `file.copy(c(new, old, csv.in), testFolder)` throws the error

> stop("more 'from' files than 'to' files")

After a few trials the problem seems to be that no path is generated by `tempdir()`. This happens on Windows and Unix (tested via Travis).
I have tried a few different things and read a few posts but nothing seems to apply to my case as I don't want to change the working directory nor I want to move the test files in the working directory. I just want to execute some file manipulations in the temp directory and then confirm the results.

When I run manually the test, it works with no problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that `tempdir()` — a longstanding base R function — is running errantly? (i.e. where's the debug code w/output that validated that assertion?) Did you also try running `tempdir(check = TRUE)` ?

Comment: I have used `capture.output(tempdir(), "test.file.txt")`, but not output was saved. I deleted that code yesterday, so I'm not sure what I got it wrong because I re-wrote it today and it **does** save a path in the text file. My bad. The problem though is solved with `tempdir(check=TRUE)` Thanks. Would you like to write that as an answer?